# WEB API HttpResponseMessage return JSONP

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, jsonp

I use the following method to create an HttpResponseMessage object and return it via my Web API project:

```
public HttpResponseMessage CreateHttpResponseMessage(string message, HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode)
{
    var stringContent = new StringContent(message, new UTF8Encoding(), "application/javascript");
    return new HttpResponseMessage(httpStatusCode)
        {
            Content = stringContent
        };
}
```

I'm using this to return a jsonp payload however it keeps returning with content type text/plain and not application/javascript.  This is causing the browser console to log this warning:

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain

The message I'm returning isn't null or empty and therefore I'm confused as to why it's behaving this way.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return `JSONP` as plain text as you are trying to return.

You need to configure your Web API to use a `JSONP` `MediaTypeFormatter`. A such formatter is offered in **[WebApiContrib](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib)**.

```
Install-Package WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp
```

Add to `Application_Start`:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()));
```

Resources:
http://stevenhollidge.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-return-jsonp-from-webapi.html
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/631685/JSONP-in-ASP-NET-Web-API-Quick-Get-Started